# GPO to lock computer when idle effects also when out of the domain

Tags: group-policy

I applied a GPO to lock screens when idle after 5 minutes.
Funny thing is, it affects computers also when not connected to the domain (at home for instance).
Any idea how to avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The laptops at home, if joined to a domain, are still domain members.  So no, domain policy is domain policy, regardless of whether or not they're on the same network as the domain.  Sorry.